# Python - function that creates boolean term if modulo operator = 0

Tags: python, boolean, operators

I have to create a function that returns true if b is a divisor of a.
I haven't done anything with functions yet.

I made this:

```
def is_divisor(a,b):
    a % b = i
    if i > 0:
        return False
    if i = 0:
        return True


is_divisor(10,5)
```

It should show true, but it doesn't.

Comment: `return not bool(a%b)`

Comment: Integer comparison in python is done with the `==` operator, not `=`

Comment: why not just `return a % b == 0` ?

Comment: `return bool(a%b)` will return false for 0 and true for non-zero. Which is backwards.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your code is on the line `if i = 0:` it should be `if i == 0`. To check for equality, use `==`.

You can also simplify this function to simply:

```
def is_divisor(a, b):
    return a % b == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def is_divisor(a, b):
    try:
        remainder = a % b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return False
    return remainder == 0
```

You should always check if you're dividing by 0! Otherwise your function is going to raise an exception.

Comment: I think you meant remainder not reminder. Good catch on DBZ exception